# Updating TextView with CountDownTimer

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I have an activity named ShowingActivity ,it has an Integer named answerNum (which is 3,4,5,6 or 7 ) and an ArrayList named SanswerList with answerNum size, I show words in this activity with using Countdowntimer, and when countdown finishes program goes to another activity.My problem is that I can't show the last word for example if answerNum is 3 it shows first and second words and does not show the third one;or if answerNum is 7 it does not shows the 7th one.
I have this piece of code in my onCreate in ShowingActivity:

```
 new CountDownTimer( answerNum * (answerNum*1000) , answerNum*1000)
    {
        int i=0;
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv1.setText(SanswerList.get(i));
            i++;
            if (i == SanswerList.size()) {
                onFinish();

            }
        }
        public void onFinish()
        {
            switch (answerNum)
            {
                case 3:
                    startActivity(new Intent(ShowingActivity.this,SedarseActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    startActivity(new Intent(ShowingActivity.this,ChardarcharActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    startActivity(new Intent(ShowingActivity.this,PanjdarpanjActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    startActivity(new Intent(ShowingActivity.this,ShishdarActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    startActivity(new Intent(ShowingActivity.this,HaftdarhaftActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

if you know another way to do this please say.

Answer (score 0):

This happens becuase, onTick will be called only `answerNum - 1` times. Hence I suggest you to set the timer for `(answerNum + 1) * 1000` time. this will give you exactly what you need

Also do not call onFinish() from onTick(). OnFinish will be called automatically when the time is completed

Answer (score 0):

Put counter increment in the last of IF statement.

```
    int i=0;
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        tv1.setText(SanswerList.get(i));

        if (i == SanswerList.size()) {
            onFinish();

        }
     i++;
    }
```

It should work. Though i did not test.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the statement to :

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer( (answerNum+1)*(answerNum*1000)  ,  answerNum*1000  )
```

and to :

```
if (i == SanswerList.size()) {
                onFinish();
            }
            tv1.setText(SanswerList.get(i));
            i++;
```

now it works well.